Traceid was missing in newrelic logs
I had a api call which runs for every 10 minutes (scheduled time) . If input was not provided to this call it runs for all ids for every 10 minutes. so i was able to see logs for ids but traceid is missing for some of ids. can I know what is the reason of missing traceid for only few ids.
i couldn't find any solution for this.
